# how to put a VALUE between mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to store some download counts with the name of the downloadfile in a database. 
This is working fine:

```
$filename = $_GET['file'];
// in combination with
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO download_manager (filename,downloads) 
                         VALUES ('$filename',1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE downloads = downloads+ 1;");
```

Now i want to escape the $_GET with mysqli_real_escape_string

When i do it like this, the script is not working anymore:

```
$filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['file']);
// in combination with
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO download_manager (filename,downloads) 
                         VALUES ('$filename',1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE downloads = downloads+ 1;");
```

How can i use the `mysqli_real_escape_string` in this example on the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from php document mysqli_real_escape_string Procedural style

`string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`

so your code should be

`$filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_GET['file']);`